# Select unique combination from a table in Mysql

Tags: mysql

My dataset has the following format;

```
Student_id Month Year Amount
1           Jan  2010  600
1           Feb  2010  391
1           Apr  2010  673
1           Jul  2010  564
5           Jan  2010  789
5           Mar  2011  298
5           Aug  2010  347
7           Jan  2010  654
7           Dec  2011  621
7           Apr  2010  450
7           Nov  2011  980
```

... & so on.

I wish my output which will have max amount for each unique id-month-year combination. Viz,

```
Student_id Month Year Amount
1          Apr   2010 673
5          Jan   2010 789
7          Nov   2011 980
```

... & like this.

How to get the output using SQL? I tried

```
select distinct * , MAX(Amount) from student_details;
```

&

```
SELECT *, MAX(Amount)
FROM student_details
WHERE Amount IN
(
    FROM student_details
    GROUP BY Student_ID, Year, Month
);
```

but the output is not as desired.

Please suggest assistance. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL:

```
SELECT t0.*
FROM student_details AS t0
LEFT JOIN student_details AS t1 ON t0.Student_id=t1.Student_id t1.Amount>t0.Amount
WHERE t1.Student_id IS NULL;
```

In SQL server:

```
SELECT T.Student_id,T.Month,T.Year,T.Amount
FROM 
(
   SELECT *,row_number() over (PARTITION BY Student_ID ORDER BY Amount DESC) as RN
   FROM student_details
)T
WHERE T.RN=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use below query

first select amount month for each user then select data which has selected month

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE amount IN (
    SELECT max(amount) FROM table group by student_id
)
```

Comment: Won't work if two students have with same amount and for one student it is max and for other student it is not max!